# What to do about a stinky sump pump

Tags: smell, sump-pump

My sump pump stinks up by basement. The sump pump works, but I think its the stagnant dirt water that sits in the sump pump over time that just stinks after a while. I have read suggestions to flush it with water every once in a while, or throw some bleach in there, but those seem like temporary solutions. Is there any way I can either trap the air/smell and/or keep it from stinking more long term?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dumping bleach in the water risks corrosion of the pump, damaging it before long. A periodic flush may be a better choice.

You can top the crock with a piece of plastic, [done in homes with radon mitigation systems](http://www.indoor-air-health-advisor.com/radon-mitigation-system.html). Note that this top must be properly done so as not to create an airlock. A trapped drain is built into the top.